# Is there a minimal time after which a cloud run instance isn't scaled down when using always allocated CPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I currently have a typical Cloud Run service implemented and want to extend it with some asynchronous functionality, which is executed in response to an incoming HTTP request. These asynchronous tasks would take no longer than 5-10 minutes.

I am now wondering if cloud run services with the "always allocated cpu"-option enabled can guarantee a 15 min window of allocated cpu time after the response of the last request has been send. I understand that an instance, which has not received a request in more than 15min is subject to termination. But is it also the other way around?

I found the following paragraph on the cloud run documentation:

> Even if CPU is always allocated, Cloud Run autoscaling is still in effect, and may terminate container instances if they aren't needed to handle incoming traffic. An instance will never stay idle for more than 15 minutes after processing a request (unless it is kept active using min instances).

(https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation)

This is the only time though that the 15 minutes time interval is mentioned in this article and also the gantt chart in the article does not show any fixed time of guaranteed cpu-allocation time after the last sent response.

Is there some guaranteed cpu-time interval after a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take from the [container contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract) was that it's best to confine yourself to the request/response flow, but have mostly been practicing this because it lends itself to having an easier time tracing requests.

While there isn't anything clear to point out that it's not permissive to use the allotted idle time for out of bound processing like you intended, perhaps it would be prudent to either use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) or the new [Cloud Run Job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) workload, if that's an option.

Comment: I guess you are right. Cloud Run Job and Cloud Functions Gen. 2 (because of concurrency support)  + PubSub actually look like they would fit well. I guess even with always allocated cpu time enabled, the cloud run use-case is really just for workloads bound to a request/response. It seems like I misunderstood the value of this new option...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation) that you provided (same with [CPU allocation (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation) documentation).

> Note that even if CPU is always allocated, Cloud Run [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) is still in effect, and may terminate container instances if they aren't needed to handle incoming traffic. An instance will never stay idle for more than 15 minutes after processing a request unless it is kept active using [minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances).

One way of keeping idle instances *permanently* available is by setting your `min-instance` with value more than `1` however this would incur cost even if the service is not actively handling any requests.

You can check this documentation [about container instance autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) for additional information.

Comment: This does not answer my question unfortunately. The request timeout refers to the time between a request and its response. I am interested on how long an instance stays active or idle (is **not** scaled down) after it does no longer process any requests. This allows asynchronous processing of some tasks which are merely triggered by an incoming request, the requested user has no need to wait for the completion of that asynchronous task though.

Comment: I would also consider it a bad practice to have such long response times and reconnection mechanism as you suggested since cloud run is not designed for stateful applications.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Kindly check.